# How to rank in parse table

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I would like to develop a ranking system for my apps users depending on how many points they have but am having a hard time thinking if I should some how query all the points in cloud code before saving a users points or if I should query all the points while saving an update to a users points and then updating the rank? Also how would I compare one to another and switch rank? Any advice on how to get on the right track?
I am using swift, xcode7, and parse as my backend.

Comment: So you're trying to make a leaderboard?
Doing this will be costly in terms of time since you will need to implement cloud code to keep checking for changed ranks in your table. Rather, if it is a game, use game center or some other leaderboard API!
And if you still want to go ahead with parse then i think you can start from here https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide

Comment: must the game center or other leaderboard API be used in a game only or can it be used in other things?

Comment: game center is used for games, but there would be other leaderboard services which you can use. You can still use GC for an app!

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a query for users whose score is greater than the current user's score and get the count to find their rank.

I'm not sure how to efficiently build a score board that shows the users with similar scores, but you could easily build a top n leaderboard by sorting and just fetching those first n results.